# Effectively cache large data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, ram

I have application which gathers information from the File system. For about 200GB hard drive the data structures in my applications use up to 1GB Ram. My data structures are in particular Dictionaries and Tries. So my questions is how to effectively cache these large data structures. What I can think of is

1. Serialization - plain text/xml, which would be faster ?
2. SWAP space - Is it possible ? I couldn't find any helpful resource
3. Local Database - I don't think this will be fast since It will have to handle a lot of queries.
4. Anything else - feel free to let me know

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Don't underestimate the speed of a database as opposed to rolling your own solution.

Comment: What makes you think that *your* data structure in not effective? What numbers do you expect/target? I.e. one 200GB file - do you expect 1GB of related data in memory (like hashes of blocks)?

Comment: My data structure is effective, its dictionary, its searching fast - no doubt. However I expect to have cases with 1TB+ hard drives, which means 4GB+ RAM, which is unacceptable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).